# Errors in springsource using grails

Tags: eclipse, grails, springsource

I am using Springsource Tool Suite as editor for grails project. The problem is at places i get an error message with a red cross saying Groovy:unable to resolve classes. But when I run the applicatios from command prompt (grails run-app), there are no errors and the application works fine. It's bit annoying to see those errors while coding.
Any ideas, what could be wrong, will be appreciated.
Cheers,
Ali

Answer (score 0):

This is a normal JVM caching/compiling behavior. You have to clean the project once upon a time. You can do this through menu: "Project -> Clean..." in Eclipse.